# MacPorts: Continue installing other updates after error

Tags: macports

Say I have the following outdated packages:

- foo
- bar
- baz

I want to update as many as them as possible, so I try to run:

```
sudo port -n -f upgrade outdated
```

However this fails with:

```
Error: org.macports.build for port foo returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port foo for details: ...
```

How can I make macports try to upgrade bar and baz, if foo fails?

I would like to generally make macports try to install/upgrade other ports if installing/upgrading some of them fails and just continue.

---

From the man page:

```
 -f       force mode (ignore state file)
```

```
 -n       don't upgrade dependencies (affects upgrade and install)
```

---

**Edit:** foo, bar & baz, are 3 total unrelated ports, that doesn't depend on each other in any way.

---

**Edit 2:** Next time I run this the outdated ports might be a, b & c, instead of foo, bar & baz, so I can't hardcode the failing ones and I can't just do:

```
sudo port update foo
sudo port update bar
sudo port update baz
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `-p` seems to work for me.

From the manpage:

```
-p       Despite any errors encountered, proceed to process multiple
         ports and commands.
```

Comment: But see the caution from a MacPorts dev below.... Using this flag is not recommended!

Answer (score 6):

You can also specify "outdated and not foo" in the upgrade command, rather than just "outdated".

Comment: see "edit 2" in question.

Answer (score 5):

MacPorts dev here; the correct answer to your question is: you don't.

There is a reason why MacPorts doesn't attempt to install a package when a dependency fails to build.

This exact question has been discussed on the macports-users mailing list not so long ago:

- “How to proceed past errors?”
  http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2012-July/029904.html
- and its follow-up thread “-p considered problematic”
  http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2012-July/029984.html

Comment: foo, bar & baz, are 3 total unrelated ports, that doesn't depend on each other in any way.

Comment: In that case you can always update them manually, i.e. sudo port upgrade baz, sudo port upgrade bar, sudo port upgrade foo.

Comment: see "edit 2" in question.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, if a MacPorts dev is speak to it.

Comment: This could be an acceptable answer if MacPorts wouldn't be anything but stable. Unfortunately, many packages depend on a lot of optional things not really needed in most cases and every second upgrade of ports fails because macports is a bunch of unstable crap.

Answer (score 2):

Considering an old closed ticket, a defect that was fixed:

[333 (dependancy failure are ignored and port continues to try and install) – MacPorts](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/333)

If I understand correctly: to continue following a failure may, in some cases, be defective.

In other words:

- it's proper (least risky) to **not** continue.

---

Postscript: I was too lazy to read the man page in its entirety (not found by the Help menu of Terminal, but that's no excuse). Following advice from someone in `irc://irc.freenode.net/#macports` I decided to leave this answer.

[image]

I never realised the `-p` option. Thanks to Tyilo.