# MacPorts: Install non-dependencies past error

Tags: software-update, macports

#### Introduction

At times, MacPorts fails to build something because of an error. Previously, @tyilo asked on AskDifferent how to ignore these error and continue installing the other ports ([link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65367/macports-continue-installing-other-updates-after-error)). Although some answers suggested using the `-p` flag, MacPorts dev (@ClemensLang) said that this should not be done because it can mess up things later.

Fair enough: it makes sense to not ignore errors when building a package that depends on a failed update.

However, there are several packages that I imagine I *could* safely update because they do not depend on the package that failed to build. I expect that there is a way to update everything possible, but when an error is encountered, to skip that package and anything that depends on it.

#### For example

Suppose I have the following packages to update with the following dependencies:

- `apple` depends on `flower`
- `tree` depends on `seed`

Suppose that `flower` fails to update. Therefore, I should not use `-p`  because it would continue trying to update `apple` and the others, and building `apple` based on a botched `flower` could cause problems.

I expect there should be a way such that if `flower` fails, MacPorts can ignore `apple` and `flower`, but continue building `seed` and `tree`.

**Is there a "best-practice" way to approach this situation? If not, why not?**

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you could do this-

```
sudo port -v upgrade outdated and not rdependentof:flower and not flower
```

Which says in english, upgrade outdated packages but not those dependent on flower and not flower

Of course you would do this after making a copy of the failed install log then cleaned the tmp location and tried to upgrade again,and if that failed then file a ticket.